# Erro no direcionamento JQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou usando o seguinte código para que após o login e senha ele seja direcionado para a respectiva página. Localmente ele funciona, mas quando subo para o servidor, ele está dando erro no Chrome:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

E no Firefox:

> Este problema pode ser causado pela desativação ou recusa de aceitar
>   cookies.

Como eu disse anteriormente, localmente ele funciona perfeitamente. O código que estou usando para redirecionamento é:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#login-form').submit(function() {
     data = $('#login-form').serialize();
     $.post("validar.php",{
            d: data,
     },
      function (d) {
        console.log(d);
       if(d == 1){
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }else{
         var redirecionar = "sistema/";
        $(window.document.location).attr('href',redirecionar);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Vale lembrar que o diretório **sistema/** existe.

Comment: E  tem alguma pagina `index` nesse diretorio ?

Comment: Olá Isac. Tem sim.

Comment: Estranho... quando tentei acessar o phpmyadmin pelo servidor, está dando esse errro: **Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)**

Comment: Vocês me desculpem se esse erro for do servidor, mas preciso ter essa segurança para ter argumentos de ir até eles.

Comment: Quais são as permissões desse diretório no servidor?

Comment: Não sei te informar, pois é uma hospedagem que estou usando. Ele funcionava e acessava tranquilamente. O servidor não é local, mas sim remoto.

Comment: O phpmyadmin voltou, mas o erro apresentado no código continua.